# impossible to parse a url containing "and space in xcode

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I'm trying to parse json in a url like:

```
NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *sampleUrl= @"http://xbmc:xbmc@192.168.1.23:8080/jsonrpc?request={\"jsonrpc\":%20\"2.0\",%20\"method\":%20\"VideoLibrary.GetMovies\",%20\"params\":%20{%20\"filter\":%20{\"field\":%20\"playcount\",%20\"operator\":%20\"is\",%20\"value\":%20\"0\"},%20\"limits\":%20{%20\"start\"%20:%200,%20\"end\":%2075%20},%20\"properties\"%20:%20[\"art\",%20\"rating\",%20\"thumbnail\",%20\"playcount\",%20\"file\"],%20\"sort\":%20{%20\"order\":%20\"ascending\",%20\"method\":%20\"label\",%20\"ignorearticle\":%20true%20}%20},%20\"id\":%20\"libMovies\"}";
    NSLog(@"%@ ",sampleUrl);

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sampleUrl]];

    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

but I get an error saying that:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

When I copy my url in my browser: it works! 
but not when I tried with xcode 
I tried changing the setting "by 22% and eliminating \ : does not work!

how do I proceed?
thanks

Comment: what the result u need

Comment: I need a list of movies for example ...

Comment: the correct url is : http://192.168.1.66:8080/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "VideoLibrary.GetMovies", "params": { "filter": {"field": "playcount", "operator": "is", "value": "0"}, "limits": { "start" : 0, "end": 75 }, "properties" : ["art", "rating", "thumbnail", "playcount", "file"], "sort": { "order": "ascending", "method": "label", "ignorearticle": true } }, "id": "libMovies"}

Comment: it is wrong url ,can u give the correct url, if it is correct,i give the answer in 5 mins ,k

Comment: bad urls? I took the examples here (http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=JSON-RPC_API/Examples) and it works from safari / chrome or firefox ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the string in `sampleUrl` is not a well formed URL (see [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)).

It contains various characters that are not allowed in URLs, for example `{` and `"`. These character have to be percent-escaped before converting to an `NSURL`.

Where does your URL string really come from?

Comment: sry brother i copied some lines

Comment: my urls are examples: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=JSON-RPC_API and here: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=JSON-RPC_API/Examples

Comment: my urls are examples: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=JSON-RPC_API and here: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=JSON-RPC_API/Examples

Comment: @QuiQuoi The posted examples are JSON. To put the JSON into a URL you have to percent-esacpe them.

Comment: Thank you I have tried with: 
  NSString * encodedText = [sampleUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
more error data is nil but not parse anything!

Answer (score -1):

here is the result that works wonders:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xbmc:xbmc@192.168.1.23:8080/jsonrpc?request={\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"VideoLibrary.GetMovies\", \"params\": { \"filter\": {\"field\": \"playcount\", \"operator\": \"is\", \"value\": \"0\"}, \"limits\": { \"start\" : 0, \"end\": 75 }, \"properties\" : [\"art\", \"rating\", \"thumbnail\", \"playcount\", \"file\"], \"sort\": { \"order\": \"ascending\", \"method\": \"label\", \"ignorearticle\": true } }, \"id\": \"libMovies\"}"];
    NSLog(@"%@ ",sampleUrl);
    NSString *encodedUrl = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:encodedUrl];


    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl]];

    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Thank you to you all for the help;)